# Deleting Elasticsearch indices that don't match a set of names through NEST

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm using NEST 5.2 to manage an Elasticsearch instance and need to delete indices that are no longer needed. I have a list of the indices that are still needed and would like to delete anything not in that list. Is there any function call that can achieve this?

If not, is there a way to get a list the indices so I can do my own filtering and delete them by name using `IElasticClient.DeleteIndexAsync`? I can see the list using the `_aliases` route with a GET request, but can't find the right incantation of `IElasticClient.Alias` that gets the same list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [cat indices API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html) can retrieve the list of indices in the cluster

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();

var indices = client.CatIndices()
    .Records
    .Select(r => r.Index)
    .ToList();
```

You could then filter these down to those you'd like to delete